# django annotate and count: how to filter the ones to include in count

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

Given a queryset, I add the count of related objects (ModelA) with the following:

```
qs = User.objets.all()
qs.annotate(modela__count=models.Count('modela'))
```

However, is there a way to count the ModelA that only meet a criteria? For example, count the ModelA where deleted_at is null?

I have tried two solutions which do not properly work.

**1) As @knbk suggested, use filter before you annotate.**

```
qs = User.objects.all().filter(modela__deleted_at__isnull=True).annotate(modela__count=models.Count('modela', distinct=True))
```

Here is the simplified version of the query generated by django:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "modela"."id") AS "modela__count", "users".*
FROM "users"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "modela" ON ( "users"."id" = "modela"."user_id" ) 
WHERE "modela"."deleted_at" IS NULL 
GROUP BY "users"."id"
```

The problem comes from the WHERE clause.
Indeed, there is a LEFT JOIN but the later WHERE conditions forced it to be a plain JOIN. I need to pull the conditions up into the JOIN clause to make it work as intended.

So, instead of

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN "modela" ON ( "users"."id" = "modela"."user_id" ) 
WHERE "modela"."deleted_at" IS NULL
```

I need the following which works when I execute it directly in plain SQL.

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN "modela" ON ( "users"."id" = "modela"."user_id" ) 
AND "modela"."deleted_at" IS NULL
```

How can I change the queryset to get this without doing a raw query?

**2) As others suggested, I could use a conditional aggregation.**

I tried the following:

```
qs = User.objects.all().annotate(modela__count=models.Count(Case(When(modela__deleted_at__isnull=True, then=1))))
```

which turns into the following SQL query:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN "modela"."deleted_at" IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS "modela__count", "users".*
FROM "users" LEFT OUTER JOIN "modela" ON ( "users"."id" = "modela"."user_id" )
GROUP BY "users"."id"
```

By doing that, I get all the users (so the LEFT JOIN works properly) but I get "1" (instead of 0) for `modela__count` for all the users who don't have any ModelA at all.
Why do I get 1 and not 0 if there is nothing to count?
How can that be changed?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In a `LEFT JOIN`, every field of `modela` could be `NULL` because of the absence of corresponding row. So

```
modela.deleted_at IS NULL
```

...is not only true for the matching rows, but also true for those `users` whose have no corresponding `modela` rows.

I think the right SQL should be:

```
SELECT COUNT(
    CASE
      WHEN
        `modela`.`user_id` IS NOT NULL  -- Make sure modela rows exist
        AND `modela`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
        THEN 1
      ELSE NULL
    END
  ) AS `modela__count`,
  `users`.*
FROM `users`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `modela`
  ON ( `users`.`id` = `modela`.`user_id` )
GROUP BY `users`.`id`
```

In Django 1.8 this should be:

```
from django.db import models
qs = User.objects.all().annotate(
    modela_count=models.Count(
        models.Case(
            models.When(
                modela__user_id__isnull=False,
                modela__deleted_at__isnull=True,
                then=1,
            )
        )
    )
)
```

**Notice**:

@YAmikep discovered that **a bug in Django 1.8.0** makes the generated SQL have an `INNER JOIN` instead of a `LEFT JOIN`, so you will lose rows without corresponding foreign key relationship. **Use Django 1.8.2 or above** version to fix that.

Comment: Thanks for your message. Using the django ORM, the generated SQL query uses a `INNER JOIN` and not a `LEFT JOIN` which does not work then because not all the Users are in the result.

Comment: @YAmikep I don't think so. I used this technique in my recent project, and everything worked fine. Also I double checked the generated SQL using `print qs.query` in a Python interactive interpreter, and I confirmed that it was `LEFT JOIN` which was generated by Django ORM. If there's still problem in your project, maybe you should check whether it is caused by other reasons.

Comment: I used `print qs.query` as well. I double checked and I confirm that an `INNER JOIN` is generated by Django ORM. Not sure why we would not get the same thing. That's weird. I use django 1.8 as well.

Comment: Try using Django 1.8.2

Comment: You're right, it seems to be fixed in 1.8.2: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24766

Comment: This makes me so happy.

Answer (score 2):

In Django 1.8 I believe this can be achieved with [conditional aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#conditional-aggregation) . However for previous versions I would do it with [`.extra`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#extra)

```
ModelA.objects.extra(select={
    'account_count': 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM account WHERE modela.account_id = account.id AND account.some_prop IS NOT NULL'
})
```

Comment: Thanks. I have updated to django 1.8. I am trying to use the conditional aggregation but cannot get it work. I updated my post with what I tried. I might misunderstood how to use the conditional aggregation. Any idea?

Comment: A quick one which I'm not sure if it's going to work -> try to use `models.Sum` instead of `models.Count`.

Comment: Ok I just tried with `Sum`. It seems to work except that I get `1` for all the ones where it is supposed to be `0`. I tried to use `default=Value(0)` in the Case but it does not change anything. :/

Comment: I tried with [Coalesce](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/database-functions/#django.db.models.functions.Coalesce) as well but it did not work. It might not be possible.

Comment: I'm surprised also. Do you actually get ModelA objects with account/s with NULL prop1. Can you see the query being produced? Is Django using LEFT or INNER JOIN?

Comment: Yes, I get all the ModelA objects.
The query uses a  `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. See the edit in my post for the full query.

Comment: FYI - It actually does not work if I have another annotate for another field. the count is wrong unless I add a distinct into the COUNT.

Comment: Thank you. I still haven't migrated to django 1.8 and don't have much experience with `conditional aggregates`. So I want to ask did you give a try to my `.extra` solution? :)

Comment: I haven't tried the `extra` solution yet but you're right, it might be the only solution. I will try it and let you know. Just one question, do you know the impact in terms of performance of this solution? I'm not sure how that is handled by Postgres but I'm wondering whether it is a good thing to have a query as an extra field? Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK there should be no performance issues. These type of subqueries are performant as a LEFT JOIN. The main drawbacks of this approach are - 1) writing a custom SQL. Which is not so bad if you move it into a queryset method for DRY and reusability. 2) can't use the field in a future filtration same as annotated field, you should use extra(where) for the purpose. 3) You can't use `extra` after `values` call, this is not the case here but sometimes annotate after values is pretty useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply filter before you annotate:

```
from django.db.models import Q, Count

qs = ModelA.objects.filter(account__prop1__isnull=False).annotate(account_count=Count('account'))
```

Comment: I wasn't sure this would work but it seems to work. I thought doing that would not return all the ModelA objects since the filter is on the ModelA manager. I must miss something. Thanks

Comment: It actually does not properly work. I saw an issue with doing this. The LEFT JOIN on the first Model does not work properly because of the filter (where clause) so I don't get all of the ModelA objects. I updated my question with a more detailed example.