# Django | Aggregate Values from Foreign Key

Tags: python, django

I have two databases, `A` and `B`.

`B` contains a `ForeignKey` to `A`.

When I do `B.objects.filter(a_id=3).values('bags').count()`, I get the number I want, `Y`.

What is the set of commands I need in order to add this number, `Y`, as an annotation into database `A`?

Ideally, this would be an `annotate` type of command.

The models look like:

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)

class B(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    a_id = models.ForeignKey(A, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bags = models.ManyToManyField(Bags)

class Bags(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
```

Comment: Can you show your models?

Comment: I'm not sure how seeing my models will help, but sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `b__bags` lookup in annotation:

```
from django.db.models import Count
A.objects.annotate(bags_count=Count('b__bags'))
```

Comment: This works! Thank you so much. Giving you the Check because you answered earlier :)

Comment: Now, if I were to filter the bags counted by some property in the bags, how could I modify it to count just those?

Comment: @Landmaster you can use Count's `filter` argument. Check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30752268/how-to-filter-objects-for-count-annotation-in-django

Comment: champ. That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Ok I must be doing something wrong... Check the difference:
`B.objects.filter(a_id=4).values('bags').count()` = 1
`B.objects.filter(a_id=4, is_true=True).values('bags').count()` = 0

But then I do this and get different values:
`A.objects.annotate(Y=Count('b__bags')).get(a_id=4).Y` = 1 
`A.objects.annotate(Y=Count('b__bags', filter=Q(b__is_true=True))).get(a_id=4).Y` = 1 also. If I do `b__is_true=False`, I also get 1.

Comment: @Landmaster sorry, don't have any idea. Try to use `Case`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30754520/641249

Comment: I'll give it a shot.. It seems like the Q Filter isn't working properly. Even if I try something like 
`A.objects.annotate(Y=Count('b__bags', filter=Q(b__id=99999999)))` I still get 1.

Comment: LMAO I have Django version 1.11.14 
**crying**

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.db.models import Count

A.objects.annotate(Y=Count('b__bags'))
```