# Django Aggregate on related field with filter

Tags: django, filter, annotations

Following problem:
I have product groups containing products. These products can be visible in the frontend or not. I determine their visibility with the method `frontend()` (which contains a filter) like so:

`product_groups.first().products.frontend()`

Now I want to determine if I want to put a link for the product group on the homepage only if there are four or more products in it.
With annotations I would do:

`product_groups.annotate(num_products=Count('products')).filter(num_products__gte=4)`

But this gives me of cause the count of *all* products and not the count of products visible in the frontend.

So how do I put the additional filter `frontend()` into my query? To be clear, I want the `Count()` not on `'products'` but on `products.frontend()`.

**Edit:**
This is not a duplicate of the suggested question. If the filter function `frontend()` was simple enough to pull out the filter and stick it in the aggregate function, the suggested question would answer my problem.

My `frontend()` function is quite complicated and an aggregate of multiple other filter functions. So I would really like to use the `frontend()` function.

**Edit:**
This needs to work in Django 1.8.

Comment: Whatever filter is in `frontend()` you can apply it to `Count` as well: `Count(products, filter=Q(...))`

Comment: @dirkgroten that's what I thought. But I cannot use `frontend()` directly? The filters I've got in `frontend()` are quite complicated and an aggregate of other functions themself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter objects for count annotation in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30752268/how-to-filter-objects-for-count-annotation-in-django)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reuse the `frontend()` method on your `Product` model's `Queryset`, then you can use [`Subquery` aggregate expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#using-aggregates-within-a-subquery-expression):

```
# assumption: `Product` has a fk to `ProductGroup`
# assumption 2: frontend() returns a `Queryset` of `Product` and is a method of `Product` model's default `Queryset`
frontend_products = Product.objects.filter(product_group=OuterRef('pk')).frontend().values('product_group')
total_products = frontend_products.annotate(total=Count('pk')).values('total')
q = product_groups.annotate(num_frontend_products=Subquery(total_products, output_field=IntegerField()))
```

Note that this will populate `num_frontend_products` with `None` instead of 0 for the groups where there isn't any corresponding product. You might want to modify the queryset further with conditional annotations to replace `None` with 0.

Comment: let me guess. There is no way to do this in Django 1.8?

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. So I can only do this manually. Thanks a lot for your effort.