# Annotating a FilteredRelation on a ManyToManyField returns nothing

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

**Models**

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass
```

```
class Report(Model):

    user = ForeignKey (
        "User",
        related_name="reports"
    )

    shared_doctors = ManyToManyField (
        "User",
        symmetrical = False,
        related_name="shared_reports"
    )
```

I have more fields on the models, but I have omitted them in the interest of shortening the problem.

**Query**

```
User.objects.annotate(
    shared_reports_user = FilteredRelation(
        'shared_reports',
        condition = Q(shared_reports__user=user)
    )
).annotate(
    shared_reports_user_count = Count('shared_reports_user')
)
```

I have brought down the query to the base level which is giving unexpected results. `user` in the first annotate is an instance of `User`.

The Query runs successfully, but the resulting QuerySet has no `shared_reports_user` key, though it has a `shared_reports_user_count` key, which has a value of `0`.

As far as I understood from the documentation, `FilteredRelation` takes a field present on the Model that it will filter on, and a named argument, `condition`, that takes a Q object as a condition to be applied to the existing field value. This leads me to believe that the first annotation should return a QuerySet annotated with a subset of `shared_reports` satisfying the condition specified in the Q object.

I'm sure my database contains values satisfying the Q object (I have manually inspected the data), and even in case there is no output, I would have expected an empty QuerySet against the key `shared_reports_user`.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I guess you must use F function like this Count(F('shared_reports_user'))

Comment: Possible, though even in that case, my `shared_report_user` key doesn't exist. If an annotation has no value, does it disappear?

Comment: No, it's not. When you use annotation Django perform left join and if it doesn't have value, it's value set as null

Comment: Let me know if it worked.

Comment: @Saber Solooki I tried it out, but it didn't change anything

Comment: I think you can find your answer in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30752268/how-to-filter-objects-for-count-annotation-in-django

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Conditional aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#conditional-aggregation) in Django 2.0 like this:

```
User.objects.annotate(
shared_reports_user_count=Count('shared_reports', filter=Q(shared_reports__user_id=user.id))
```

Comment: Yes, that solves the problem of finding the shared_reports_user_count, but I still need the actual list of shared_reports_user.

Comment: This is another question. But if you wan shared_reports for each user you can use this : users = User.objects.rest_of_your_query(). shared_reports_user_for_user1 = users[0].shared_doctors.all()

Comment: Yeah, I discovered some new information.


Using an `F` on `shared_reports_user` unwinds the QuerySet and gives an array of users each having 1 report in shared_reports_user_f. So my guess is that internally, shared_reports_user is attached, but not as an attribute.
Also, after this, the Count annotation give correct values.


I'm accepting your answer, and I'll post a more detailed answer soon for posteriority.

Comment: @Klys did you ever find a way to access `shared_reports_user`? I'm having the same issue

Comment: I did, but haven't worked on Python since 

Comment: I'll have a look in about 12 hours in my old codebase