# Annotate A object with the count of related B objects with Subquery

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I am trying to annotate User with the count of delayed leads objects. The calculation of delayed leads is complex (uses RawSQL) implemented using a custom model manager. Hence, I am trying to implement this using a subquery.

```
sq = Lead.delayed.filter(assigned_to_id=OuterRef('pk'))
User.objects.annotate(num=Count(Subquery(sq.count())))
```

However, I keep getting this error:

```
 ValueError: This queryset contains a reference to an outer query and may only be used in a subquery.
```

UPDATE:

I tried adding only('id') so my code:

```
sq = Lead.delayed.filter(assigned_to_id=OuterRef('id')).only('id')
User.objects.annotate(num=Count(Subquery(sq)))
```

This generated the sql query:

```
SELECT `auth_user`.`id`, `auth_user`.`username`, `auth_user`.`first_name`,
`auth_user`.`last_name`, COUNT((SELECT U0.`id` FROM
`lead` U0 WHERE U0.`assigned_to_id` = (`auth_user`.`id`))) AS `count`
FROM `auth_user` GROUP BY `auth_user`.`id`;
```

This is throwing error:

`ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row`

I would like to have my query generated as:

```
SELECT `auth_user`.`id`, `auth_user`.`username`, `auth_user`.`first_name`,
`auth_user`.`last_name`, (SELECT COUNT(U0.`id`) FROM `marketing_lead` U0 WHERE
(more complex conditions here) U0.`assigned_to_id` = (`auth_user`.`id`)) AS `count`
FROM `auth_user` GROUP BY `auth_user`.`id`;
```

How can I acheive that using django ORM?

Comment: I guess your problem is that you don't specify 'only' function of your subquery. You must use Lead.delayed.filter(assigned_to_id=OuterRef('pk')).only('id). Also this link can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43770118/simple-subquery-with-outerref/43771738

Comment: @SaberSolooki I have updated my questions. After adding only I got SQL error.

Comment: Why you are not trying Conditional aggregation. I don't know if you can use it in your complex query that you mentioned or not. See my answer in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59472592/annotating-a-filteredrelation-on-a-manytomanyfield-returns-nothing/59472963#59472963

Answer (score 1):

Alternative question label might be **How to use `Count()` not perform grouping (`GROUP BY`)** or **How to count all in a `Subquery`**

Check [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47371514/12520350) for custom `Count` function to just perform simple count on any queryset **without** grouping.

---

Unfortunately, so far haven't found native django option for this.

Answer (score 0):

Though the answer from  Oleg was quite close to my requirement but I was still getting an SQL error on the query generated by django. Hence, I ended up implementing  using [cursor.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/sql/#connections-and-cursors)