# Count field choices in a model?

Tags: django, django-models

Im new to django and Im helping in creating a website, now what they've requested is to show a specific number and Im trying to use a for loop it goes something like this:

```
    class Students(models.Model):
...
section = (('1', '1'), ('2', '2'), ('3', '3'), ('4', '4'), ('5', '5'), ('6', '6'))
BlockNumber = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=section)
```

now what I want to do is to count each section choice in the Students model class.
I've tried using the code below to count each choice:

```
def yearCount(request):
    year = Students.objects.all(Count('year'))
    blocks = Students.onjects.all(Count('section'))
    context = {'year': year,'blocks': blocks}
    return render(request, './chairperson/students/student_bsit1.html', context)
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: `count each section choice in the Students model class` can you elaborate this...?? and what is the sample result which you are expecting...??

Comment: Are you trying to get a count of the number of students which have 1 as their section, 2 as their section and so on? If so have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30752268/how-to-filter-objects-for-count-annotation-in-django

Comment: `blocks = Students.onjects.all(Count('section'))` has a rogue `n` in `objects`

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to count on the number of students with particular sectors from your choices:

```
from django.db.models import Q, Count
student_counts = Students.objects.annotate(
    section1_count=Count('BlockNumber', filter=Q(BlockNumber='1')),
    section2_count=Count('BlockNumber', filter=Q(BlockNumber='2')),
    # section3_count... etc
)
```

You mentioned your new to Django so see here's a couple notes/tips on code styling, your model names should be plural. `Students` should be `Student` and your fields should be `block_number` instead of `BlockNumber`. Functions should be `year_count` instead of `yearCount`. [Here](https://realpython.com/python-code-quality/) is a good article to improve your code readability and maintainability. It would be good to get a linter up and running on your editor to help with this earlier in the project so you can get used to the Python style guides.