# How to fix AttributeError: 'WhereNode' object has no attribute 'select_format', raised by Django annotate()?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

There are many similar questions on SO, but this specific error message did not turn up in any of my searches:

```py
AttributeError: 'WhereNode' object has no attribute 'select_format'
```

This was raised when trying to `annotate()` a Django queryset with the (boolean) result of a comparison, such as the [gt lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#gt) in the following simplified example:

```py
Score.objects.annotate(positive=Q(value__gt=0))
```

The model looks like this:

```py
class Score(models.Model):
    value = models.FloatField()
    ...
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This case can be fixed using the [ExpressionWrapper()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/expressions/#expressionwrapper-expressions)

```py
Score.objects.annotate(
    positive=ExpressionWrapper(Q(value__gt=0), output_field=BooleanField()))
```

From the docs:

> `ExpressionWrapper` is necessary when using arithmetic on `F()` expressions with different types ...

The same apparently holds for `Q` objects, although I could not find any explicit reference in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects).

Answer (score 3):

You can also get this error message if you are trying to filter a count annotation, and accidentally put the filter clause in the wrong place.  e.g. if you're following [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48649024/303056) but instead of writing

```
events = Event.objects.annotate(
    paid_participants=Count('participants', filter=Q(participants__is_paid=True))
)
```

like the example says, you accidentally write

```
events = Event.objects.annotate(
    paid_participants=Count('participants'), filter=Q(participants__is_paid=True)
)  # WRONG
```

then you will get this error message.  It's a silly mistake, but could cost you an hour or two, and `ExpressionWrapper` won't help.  (Hopefully this helps somebody else.)

Comment: Good point. The `events` queryset is created without issue, but the error is raised when you try to evaluate it, e.g. `events.first()`.