# Django annotate(),Count()

Tags: django, count, django-annotate

I get the output like this using annotate() and Count()

```
<QuerySet [{'pid': 11, 'status': 'Completed', 'status__count': 3}, {'pid': 11, 'status': 'Hold', 'status__count': 12}, {'pid': 11, 'status': 'InProgress', 'status__count': 2}, {'pid': 11, 'status': 'New', 'status__count': 3}, }]
```

this is the code I write to get like this

view.py:

```
tasks = Task.objects.values('pid','status').annotate(Count('status')).order_by('pid')
```

Actually I want my output like this

```
<QuerySet [{'pid': 11, 'Completed': 3, 'Hold': 12,  'InProgress': 2,'New': 3},}]
```

How can I do it?

Comment: can you share `models.py`

Comment: class Task(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1000,default="",null=False)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=30,default="",null=False)
    pid = models.ForeignKey(Projects,on_delete=CASCADE)

Comment: but hows is this possible with same `Project id` but different `status`? One project can have one status right?

Comment: annotate with condition could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30752268/how-to-filter-objects-for-count-annotation-in-django

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
Task.objects.values('pid').annotate(
    completed = Count('status', filter=Q(status='Completed')),
    hold=Count('status', filter=Q(status="Hold")),
    in_progress=Count('status', filter=Q(status="InProgress"))
).order_by('pid')
```

More information can be found in [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/).

Answer (score 1):

An another method i found this also worked
[image]

Thanks you

Comment: You should not put screenshots of code. Please put the actual code within ``` ``` block.