# Using custom queries with Django annotate

Tags: django

In annotate. When counting records, how can I use a custom query to narrow down what to count?

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

```
class Tweet(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey("User", related_name="tweet")
    favorite = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = TweetQuerySet.as_manager()


class TweetQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def buzzed(self):
        return self.filter(
            is_active=True,
            favorite__gte=100
        )
```

```
# I want to count only the tweets returned using the buzzed query.
users = User.objects.annotate(tweet_count=Count("tweet"))
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is related to [How to filter objects for count annotation in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30752268/how-to-filter-objects-for-count-annotation-in-django)

Just like stated in post above, you can use filter argument in Count class.

In your case, you could do something like:

```
users = User.objects.annotate(tweet_count=Count("tweet", filter=Q(is_active=True) & Q(favorite__gte=100)))
```

If you'd like to have this logic in `TweetQuerySet` manager, you can make a method, that returns this exact code, like this:

```
def buzzed_tweets_count(self):
    return self.annotate(tweet_count=Count("tweet", filter=Q(is_active=True) & Q(favorite__gte=100)))
```

And then call it:

```
users = User.objects.buzzed_tweets_count()
```